# Fullcalendar v3.6.2 startParam and endParam

Tags: jquery, json, laravel-5, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

How to use startParam and endParam in fullcaledar? I don´t know much about jQuery and Javascript. The view is in the route: `example.com/agenda`, then I thought that I have to put the **startParam** and **endParam** in the following way in my script:

```
    startParam: 'agenda.start',
    limitParam : 'agenda.limit',
```

The idea is to avoid the slow loading of events (about 10 seconds) by limiting both parameters so that only loads what is seen on the page at that moment. Have I understood it well? This does not work, I mean that it continues to load slowly, the rest works perfect. How should I do it? Thanks.

This is the complete file **my-fullcalendar.js** I collect data from a json file:

```
var currentLangCode = $("#lang_js").data('value');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    locale:currentLangCode,
    eventColor: '#58C1AB',
    eventTextColor: '#fff',
    startParam: 'agenda.start',
    limitParam : 'agenda.limit',

    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {  // when some one click on any event

        if(currentLangCode == 'en'){
            startdate = moment(event.start).format('ddd, MMM D');
            enddate = moment(event.end).format('ddd, MMM D YYYY');
        }else{
            startdate = moment(event.start).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY');
            enddate = moment(event.end).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY');
        }

        starttime = moment.utc((event.start), "H:mm");
        endtime = moment.utc((event.end), "H:mm");

        var s_time = starttime.format("H:mm");
        var e_time = endtime.format("H:mm");

        if(s_time == '0:00'){
            var mytime = '';
        }else{
            var mytime = '<img src="images/web/icons/clock.svg" class="icono" width="18"> ' + s_time + ' - ' + e_time;
        }

        if(enddate == startdate){
            var mydate = '<img src="images/web/icons/date.svg" class="icono" width="18"> ' + startdate;
        }else if(event.end == null){
            var mydate = '<img src="images/web/icons/date.svg" class="icono" width="18"> ' + startdate;
        }else{
            var mydate = '<img src="images/web/icons/date.svg" class="icono" width="18"> ' + startdate + ' - ' + enddate;
        }

        if((event.imagen)){
            var myimage = '<img src="'+(event.imagen)+'" width="100%"/>';
        }else{
            var myimage = '';
        }
        var myplace = '<img src="images/web/icons/map-marker.svg" class="icono" width="18"/> ' +(event.lugar);

        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#modalPlace').html(myplace);
        $('#modalDate').html(mydate);
        $('#modalTime').html(mytime);
        $('#modalImage').html(myimage);

        $('#calendarModal').modal();
    },

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    events:{
        url:'agenda/evento'
    },


});
```

And this is **the controller**. I´m using Laravel 5.4:

```
class EventoController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
        return view('web.agenda.index', compact('calendar'));
}

public function api(Request $request)
{

    $events = Evento::where('active', '1')->orderBy('start_date')->get();

    $lang = Session::get('lang');
    if($lang == 'en') $lang_id = '2';
    elseif($lang == 'pt') $lang_id = '3';
    else $lang_id = '1';

    $data = [];
    foreach($events as $event){

        foreach($event->langs as $event_lang){
            if($event_lang->lang_id == $lang_id and $event_lang->evento_id == $event->id){

                // title and place
                $title[]=$event_lang->text;
                $place[]=$event_lang->place;

                $id[] = $event->id;

                // start
                if($event->start_time){
                    $start[] = $event->start_date.'T'.$event->start_time;
                } else{
                    $start[] = $event->start_date;
                }

                // end
                if($event->end_time){
                    $end[] = $event->start_date.'T'.$event->end_time;
                }elseif($event->end_date){
                    $end[] = $event->end_date;
                }else{
                    $end[] ='';
                }

                // image
                if(count($event->images)){
                    $imagen = Image::select('path')->where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Evento')->where('imageable_id', $event->id)->first();
                    $image[] = $imagen->path;
                }else{
                    $image[] = '';
                }
            }
        }

    }

    $count = count($id);

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $data[$i] = array(
            "title"=>$title[$i],
            "lugar"=>$place[$i],
            "start"=>$start[$i],
            "end"=>$end[$i],
            "imagen"=>$image[$i],
        );
    }

    return response()->json($data);

}

}
```

Comment: "does not work" means what, exactly? An error? Unexpected result or behaviour? Please clarify

Comment: Anyway, two obvious problems: 1) You didn't read the fullCalendar docs properly - there's no such parameter as "limitParam". https://fullcalendar.io/docs/endParam is what you want for specifying the name of the parameter which defines the end of the time period. 2) I don't see anywhere in your PHP where you actually make use of these values to restrict the output of your query.

Comment: Thanks, ADyson. With "Does not work" I mean that it continues to load slowly, the rest works perfect.

Comment: well that's probably because of a combination of the two things I mentioned above. It's likely loading all your events instead of just the ones between the dates actually being displayed on the calendar.

Comment: Yes, I think that I understand, but I don´t know how to do that in my code. Could you show me an example and if it´s possible explain it?

Comment: I mean, I know that then I have to pass the two parameters: startParam and endParam but where and how?

Comment: fullCalendar passes them for you automatically when it makes the ajax request to fetch the events. They will be querystring parameters. All this is explained at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed. By setting the  startParam and endParam _options_, you are telling the calendar to change the _name_ of the parameters. More than likely, this is unnecessary, unless the default names ("start" and "end") conflict with other custom parameters you wish to send, but it seems like in this case you don't have that problem. So probably, setting these options is not needed.

Comment: Regardless of what you decide to name the parameters, you PHP code then has to receive those parameters, and use the values as variables in a WHERE clause in the SQL, to restrict the events returned to those whose start date falls between those two dates. Now, I don't know Laravel very well but I'm quite sure they will have tutorials which show you how to read querystring parameter from a request object, and from your code above it seems you already know how to set a "where" in your query.

Comment: Ok, thanks, ADyson I´m going to see how to get the parameters in the controller before the where and I tell you if I get it ;)

Comment: BTW you could also benefit by removing the "orderBy" clause - fullCalendar doesn't need the events to be in any particular order, it will obviously just place them on the calendar according to their date, no matter what order they are received. And if your "startDate" column is not indexed in your database, and you have a lot of records, ordering by that column could slow things down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167574/discussion-between-nature-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved it** thanks to ADyson for his answers:

In the controller, I added:

```
    $from= $request->start;
    $to= $request->end;

    $events = Evento::where('active', '1')->whereBetween('start_date', [$from, $to])->get();
```